# sed remove spaces (multiple encoding) from end of line

Tags: text-processing, sed, character-encoding

I like remove *spaces* from the beginning and the end of line.

```
result="$(mysql -r --column-names=0 -e "SELECT String FROM Table")"
echo $result | cat -E
+stringA +StringB     $
echo $result | sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]\)\+//g' | sed 's/\([[:blank:]]\)\+$//g' | cat -E
+stringA +StringB     $
```

I copied the string with my mouse, and inserted it with the *mouse key 3* (press down the wheel)

```
echo '+stringA +StringB     ' | sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]\)\+//g' | sed 's/\([[:blank:]]\)\+$//g' | cat -E
+stringA +StringB     $
```

now i pressed the key <kbd>↑</kbd>, navigate to the spaces and replace it with <kbd>del</kbd> and  <kbd>space</kbd>

```
echo '+stringA +StringB     ' | sed 's/^\([[:blank:]]\)\+//g' | sed 's/\([[:blank:]]\)\+$//g' | cat -E
+stringA +StringB$
```

and now the `sed` command matched and deleted the **spaces**.
How can i convert <del>*wrong spaces*</del> *non-breaking space* to *normal spaces*?

```
echo $LANG
en_US.UTF-8
$bash --version
GNU bash, version 4.3.30(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
mysql -e "SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%char%'"
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| Variable_name            | Value                      |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
| character_set_client     | utf8                       |
| character_set_connection | utf8                       |
| character_set_database   | utf8                       |
| character_set_filesystem | binary                     |
| character_set_results    | utf8                       |
| character_set_server     | utf8                       |
| character_set_system     | utf8                       |
| character_sets_dir       | /usr/share/mysql/charsets/ |
+--------------------------+----------------------------+
```

### Update1:

```
echo '+stringA +stringB         ' | od -tx1z
0000000 2b 73 74 72 69 6e 67 41 20 2b 73 74 72 69 6e 67  >+stringA +string<
0000020 42 c2 a0 c2 a0 c2 a0 c2 a0 c2 a0 c2 a0 c2 a0 c2  >B...............<
0000040 a0 c2 a0 0a                                      >....<
0000044
echo '+stringA +stringB         ' | od -tx1z
0000000 2b 73 74 72 69 6e 67 41 20 2b 73 74 72 69 6e 67  >+stringA +string<
0000020 42 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 20 0a                 >B         .<
0000033
echo '+stringA +stringB         ' | od -c
0000000   +   s   t   r   i   n   g   A       +   s   t   r   i   n   g
0000020   B 302 240 302 240 302 240 302 240 302 240 302 240 302 240 302
0000040 240 302 240  \n
0000044
echo '+stringA +stringB         ' | od -c
0000000   +   s   t   r   i   n   g   A       +   s   t   r   i   n   g
0000020   B                                      \n
0000033
```

the `echo`-commands 1 and 3 are copied with mouse key 3
the `echo`-commands 2 and 4 are with *normal* spaces

### Update2:

i inserted the `sed`command with `[^[:graph:]]` but it does not change the out.

```
for UKWID in 123 456 678; do
    result="$(mysql -r --column-names=0 -e "SELECT String FROM Table WHERE id = $UKWID")"
    echo "$result" | sed 's/^[^[:graph:]]*//;s/[^[:graph:]]*//' | cat -E
done
+stringA +stringB         $
   +stringc +stringx    $
+stringe +stringf      $
```

Comment: what does mean your *wrong spaces to normal spaces*?

Comment: I mean the spaces in the `$result` var, they are different (i think the encodeing) to normal spaces, which i inserted with my keyboard. There are no visible differ. @RomanPerekhrest

Comment: non-breaking spaces maybe? Do you have to do it with sed or are there other options?

Comment: of course, whitespaces are not visible at the end of the line. But the initial nuance is that your mysql query returns column values which have different number of spaces.

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest, yes the mysql select statement can return strings with a multible number of spaces at EOL

Comment: @FatMax, run the input with the weird spaces through `echo "$result" | od -c` (or `| od -tx1z` (GNU coreutils)) so we can see what they really are

Comment: @ilkkachu i would prefer `sed` or other bash tools, other tools are also available

Comment: @FaxMax,  is your goal to just return a string(mysql result) without leading and trailing whitespaces?

Comment: @RomanPerekhrest yes it is

Comment: @ilkkachu i updated my question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are blanks (like U+00A0 the non-breaking space) or invisible characters (like backspace or U+200B) that are not classified as `[:blank:]` or even `[:space:]` in some locales.

In theory, you should be able to trim all non-graphical characters with:

```
sed 's/^[^[:graph:]]*//;s/[^[:graph:]]*$//'
```

But again on some locales in some systems that doesn't work for U+00A0.

```
perl -Mopen=locale -lpe 's/^\P{Graph}+|\P{Graph}+$//'
```

Works for your U+00A0, but doesn't for U+200B

You could also always adds those characters individually by yourself. Using zsh-like `$'\u....'` expansion (also supported by recent versions of bash ad some other shells):

```
trim=$'[[:space:][:cntrl:]\u00a0\u200b]*'
sed "s/^$trim//;s/$trim\$//"
```

Comment: I updated my question, it doesn't solve my problem.

Comment: @FaxMax, like I said it doesn't work in some locale that incorrectly classifies U+00A0 as a _graphical_ character. That's the case of locales of GNU systems. Use `perl` instead.

Answer (score -1):

Use below command to remove empty spaces at beginning and end of the line
Command Let me know for any other additional requirement

---

```
 sed -r "s/^\s+//g"| sed -r "s/\s+$//g"
```

---

Comment: Note that's GNU `sed` specific. On most GNU systems however, that doesn't work for the OP's U+00A0 character, as `\s` is just short for `[[:space:]]` and the non-breaking space is not considered a spacing character in GNU locales.